# $\cup B$ in Zorn's lemma

Tags: elementary-set-theory

In Zorn's lemma we have if for every chain $B\subseteq A$, we have $\cup B\in A$, thereby $A$ contains a maximal element.
My question is that isn't $\cup B$ just equal to the maximal element of $B$?

For exmaple:

$A = \{a,b,c,d\}$,
$B = \{a,b,c\}$,  $a\subseteq b \subseteq c$

so $B$ is a chain in $A$. Isn't $\cup B$ just equal to $c$? And of course $c\in A$ because $B\subseteq A$. So For every chain in $A$, its union is in $A$. What's the point? Where am I wrong?

Comment: Hi John! Good question. Think about chains that have infinitely many elements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to see better the setting of Zorn's lemma is to see an example where it breaks.

Let $A$ be the set of all *finite* subsets of $\mathbb N$. It is fairly obvious that $A$ does not have a maximal element. (For, that element would be a finite set, so it won't be the whole $\mathbb N$, so you could pick an element of $\mathbb N$ outside it, add it to our purported maximal element, and make a bigger finite set in $A$.)

Now, how is the chain property broken? Just look at the sets $\{0\}, \{0,1\}, \{0,1,2\},\ldots$: they form a chain of elements in $A$ (as all are finite), but their union is not in $A$ because their union is the entire $\mathbb N$ - an infinite set.

Answer (score 4):

Your idea that $\bigcup B$ is the maximal element of the chain $B$ would be correct if $B$ had a maximal element. But an infinite chain might not have a maximal element, and then $\bigcup B$ would  not be a member of $B$. So proving that $\bigcup B\in A$ is often nontrivial.